# How to vertically center the text in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView in my iOS (swift) app and i am using loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: ). Now the problem is that I want the HTML to be vertically centered in the frame. The text is variable in length. How can I do that?

This is the screenshot of the HTML from Xcode:

[image: Figure 1]

This is image of the output. The top HTML is on the upper side, I want it to be centrally aligned in its view (the view is 300 points from the top):

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Post a screenshot or the HTML please

Comment: @Asleepace added the screenshots.

Comment: Hi Amir - it strikes me that the best way to do this would be to edit the HTML, either by injecting some inline CSS or by applying an external stylesheet, rather than trying to tweak the WKWebView per se.

Comment: Easy. x = 10... that was the question... right?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this HTML with inline CSS, you can replace the stuff in between the divs that you want centered:

```
  <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;height:100%;justify-content:center;">
    <p>You content here</p>
  </div>
```

This code works for me using Swift 3.0 on an iPhone 6 simulator

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var webView:WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(webView!);
        addHTML()
    }
    
    func addHTML() {
        let html = "<html><body><div style='height:100%;background-color:black;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;'><p style='color:white;font-size:100px;'>Asleepace</p></div></body></html>";
        webView!.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

### Example Output

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in iOS app. It doesn't even work on html unless i add height:500px to it. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_document

Comment: @AmirSiddique Ya the height:100% is meant to fill a parent container, wasn't sure which dimensions you were using.

Comment: @AmirSiddique I just tested it in xcode, seems to be working fine for me, take a look at the demo code above

Comment: not really. I got to a compromised solution by using padding-top but later did the hard work, and manually set the WkWebView height for each html string in the database. It was tedious but it delivered exactly what I wanted.